# Open Chrome URL from chrome://chrome-urls/ list

Tags: windows, google-chrome, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I open page `chrome://settings/downloads` using keyboard shortcut?

I tried creating a Windows shortcut with the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" chrome://settings
```

but it just opens a new Chrome window with blank new tab.
(at the same time `"C:\Program Files\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" stackoverflow.com/` of course works great)

And C++ script of course gives me the same result - blank new tab. (I used `system()` from `<windows.h>`)